# How to change my subsection format to Times New Roman and bold?

Tags: fonts, section-titles

I am very new to Latex. For some reason the subsection in my document is appearing in italics, both the subsection number and the text. I have been trying to get them to appear in Times New Roman bold. The following command only changes the font of the subsection heading, but not the section number.

```
\newcommand{\ssubsection}[1]{%
\subsection[#1]{\raggedright\normalfont\rm #1}}
```

No success with using `titlesec` package or anything else since most of them are changing the placement and subsection number altogether.
Could anybody help at all?

Cheers

Comment: What document class are you using? It depends on each specific class.

Comment: not related, but you should'nt use \rm but \rmfamily to change the family - \rm is not a core latex command and not defined in every class.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I am using article class. Any help?